# Show that if a group $G$ of finite order has elements of order $d,$ then $G$ has subgroups of order of every divisor of $d.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

My attempt: Let $G$ be cyclic and let $a\in G$ has order $d.$
Since order of an element of a group divides order of that group, and since converse of Lagrange theorem is true for cyclic groups, so we can have cyclic subgroups of order of every divisors of $d.$
However, I am stuck to prove for an arbitrary group of finite order.

Comment: Consider the subgroups generated by $a^n$.

Comment: Well, in general, take $g \in G$ an element of order $d$ and consider the cyclic subgroup generated by $g$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's an element of order $d$, say $g\in G$, then $\langle g\rangle$ is cyclic of order $d$.

Answer (score 1):

If $c$ divides $d$, the order of $a^{d\over c}$ is $c$.